# How to filter tests with an array of meta value through testcaferc.json

Tags: testcafe

I have tests with different meta data values.

Sample code

```
import { t, Selector } from "testcafe";

fixture("Filtering test cases example  2");

test("test case 1", async (t) => {
  console.log("Test case 1");
}).meta( {"type" : "smoke", "environment" : "qa" , "severity" : "high" });

test("test case 2", async (t) => {
  console.log("Test case 2");
}).meta( {"type" : "smoke", "environment" : "qa" , "severity" : "low" });

test("test case 3", async (t) => {
  console.log("Test case 3");
}).meta( {"type" : "regression", "environment" : "production" , "severity" : "high" });

test("test case 4", async (t) => {
  console.log("Test case 4");
}).meta( {"type" : "regression", "environment" : "qa" , "severity" : "low" });
```

How to configure the .testcaferc.json file to run with severity low and high.

I was looking for something similar to following to filter the test cases.

```
{
  "browsers": "chrome",
  "filter": {
    "testMeta": {
      "severity" : ["high", "low"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex usage scenario and I recommend you use the `.testcaferc.js` configuration file instead of `.testcaferc.json`.
Please take a look at the following example:

```
module.exports = {
    filter: function (testName, fixtureName, fixturePath, testMeta, fixtureMeta) {
        return testMeta.severity === 'high' ||
            testMeta.severity === 'low' ||
            testMeta.severity === 'medium';
    }
}
```

You can find more information about the usage of the `filter` method in this topic: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402657/reference/testcafe-api/runner/filter#header